# Cannot import Firebase via cocoapod in swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3

I am trying to integrate Firebase Google SignIn in my swift project but when I install the SDK via cocoapods I get error "No Such Module" for `import Firebase`. I have tried solutions provided in similar questions but none of them helped me. I am mentioning my podfile below.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'swiftapp' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod "Bottomsheet"
pod "SearchTextField"
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

end
```

I am also attaching an image which shows all the `Firebase` modules available in my project.[image]

Edit:- I've updated my cocoapods before installing Firebase in my project. And, for testing purpose I tried installing Firebase in a new project and it works perfectly in that project.

Edit:- I'm using 1.3.1 version of cocoapods.

[image]

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing DerivedData

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Tried that but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can import that part of Firebase which you need in code. For e.g.:- If you need to do firebase authentication, then you can import FirebaseAuth alone. So, it depends on which part of Firebase you work on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, updating cocoapods to 1.3.0 should solve it.

Also you should have

> pod 'Firebase/Core'

in your podfile, not

> pod 'Firebase'

Comment: I had updated the cocoapods before installing Firebase. Installing Firebase via cocoapods works perfectly in a new project but in my existing project I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I am using cocoapods 1.3.1.

Comment: i wasn't talking about cocoapods